# How to find the values in a dataframe and the one after it?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that contains river levels and rainfalls together in a DataFrame called Hourly. I would like to be able to loop through for every rainfall value and collect its river level value, plus the next river level reading.
For Example:

```
River Level Rainfall
0.876       0.0
0.877       0.8
0.882       0.0
```

In this case if I was looking for the values for 0.8mm of rainfall, I would like it to return the 0.877 that is in the same row as the 0.8 and also the 0.882 in the row immediately after.
I would like it to output:

```
0.877
0.882
```

Currently I have a loop that goes through and locates all the rows for a given rainfall value but cannot figure out how to get the one row after value.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: there is no `0.2` in column `Rainfall` of your sample data

Comment: Can you share expected output?

Comment: @AndyL. hi, thanks I have updated it now.

Comment: @E.Zeytinci I have updated the question to include the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
s = df.Rainfall.eq(0.8)
out = df.loc[s | s.shift(), 'River Level']

Out[364]:
1    0.877
2    0.882
Name: River Level, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

shift is the way to go as suggested by @Andy L. If you are looking for alternatives here's another way (after Wayne suggestion):

```
rainfall_value = 0.8
index = data[data.Rainfall == rainfall_value].index.tolist()
index = [item for x in index for item in [x, x+1]]
result = data.iloc[index]
print(result['River Level']) 
# 1  0.877
# 2  0.882
```

Comment: I was pursuing something along these lines too, but the OP says the code "locates all the rows for a given rainfall value". As written, your solution only handles the first instance. Above the result line I'd suggest you insert `index = [item for x in index for item in [x, x+1]]`. And then replace the `result` line with `result = data.iloc[index]`.

Comment: @Wayne you are totally right, list comprehension should solve it! I updated the answer accordingly!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this method works for me also but I have marked the other one as correct for its simplicity.